# Is the subbasis of a topological space preserved under an open continuous map?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces, and $f:X\to Y$ a continuous, surjective, and open function. If $\{S_\alpha\}_\alpha$ is a subbasis of $X$, is $\{f(S_\alpha)\}_\alpha$ a subbasis of $Y$ ? That is, if the topology on $X$ is the smallest one containing $\{S_\alpha\}_\alpha$, is the topology on $Y$ the smallest one containing $\{f(S_\alpha)\}_\alpha$ ? Note that the image of a basis of $X$ is a basis of the topology on $Y$.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is NO: Let
$$f:\mathbb{Z}\to\{0,1\}$$
be a function defined by $f(\mbox{even})=0$ and $f(\mbox{odd})=1$.
Give $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\{0,1\}$ the discrete topologies. Then $f$ is open and continuous. The rays in $\mathbb{Z}$  of the form
$$(n,\infty)\qquad\mbox{and}\qquad(-\infty,n)$$
form a subbasis of $\mathbb{Z}$. Their images in $\{0,1\}$ are all the entire set $\{0,1\}$, so they do not form a subbasis of the discrete topology on $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: Nice example. +1 from me.

Answer (score -2):

I think yes. Let's explore!

> Let $f \colon X \to Y$ be an open continuous map, where $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces. Let $\mathscr{S}$ be a subbasis for $X$. Then the collection
>   $$ \big\{ \, f(S) \, \colon \, S \in \mathscr{S} \, \big\} \tag{1} $$
>   is a subbasis for the subspace $F(X)$ of $Y$. [Does this conclusion hold?]

In what follows, I'll be using the approach used by Munkres in defining subbasis for a topological spaces.

Proof:

> First, we note that, as 
>   $$ \bigcup_{S \in \mathscr{S}} S = X, $$
>   so we must also have
>   $$ \bigcup_{S \in \mathscr{S}} f(S) = f \big( \bigcup_{S \in \mathscr{S}} S  \big) = f(X). $$
>   Thus the collection (1) is a subbasis for some topology on $f(X)$.
>
> For any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and for any sets $S_1, \ldots, S_n \in \mathscr{S}$, the set 
>   $S_1 \cap \cdots \cap S_n$ is a basis set for the topology of $f(X)$, and conversely any basis set for the topology of $X$ is of the form $S_1 \cap \cdots \cap S_n$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $S_1, \ldots, S_n \in \mathscr{S}$.
>
> Let $V$ be any open set in $f(X)$. Then $V = f(X) \cap V^\prime$ for some open set $V^\prime$ in $Y$. Then we find that
>   $$
> \begin{align} &= f^{-1} \big( f(X) \cap V^\prime \big) \\
> &= f^{-1} \big( f(X) \big) \cap f^{-1} \big( V^\prime \big) \\
> &= X \cap f^{-1} \big( V^\prime \big) \\
> &= f^{-1} \big( V^\prime \big),
> \end{align}
> $$
>   which is an open set in $X$, being the inverse image under the continuous map $f$ of an open set $V^\prime$ in $Y$.
>
> In short, for any open set $V$ in $f(X)$, the inverse image $f^{-1}(V)$ is again an open set in $X$ and thus expressable as a union of sets of the form $S_1 \cap \cdots \cap S_n$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $S_1, \ldots, S_n \in \mathscr{S}$.
>
> However, there is one problem: Unless $f$ is injective, the equality
>   $$ f \big( S_1 \cap \cdots \cap S_n \big) = f \big( S_1 \big) \cap \cdots \cap f \big( S_n \big) $$
>   need not hold.
>
> Moreover, although
>   $$ f\big( f^{-1}(V) \big) \subset V $$
>   holds, the equality
>   $$ f\big( f^{-1}(V) \big) = V $$
>   does not hold in general if $f$ is not surjective.

Please refer to Sec. 2 in Munkres's *Topology*, 2nd edition.

Can you figure out the answer to your question from this?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy can you please have a look at my post and oblige me by completing the proof or giving the necessary counter-examples?

Comment: It is pretty obvious that the real problem here is that the image of an intersection need not be intersection of  the images. The real question is whether one can come up with a counter-example. @Saaqib Mahmood

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy yes sir. You're absolutely right.